# Applying different rules based on url pattern in Reactive spring security

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2

I am having different group of endpoints like API, login and open access.

Wants to trigger oauth only for login endpoint. 401 error for api endpoint without valid session.

I was trying to put multiple SecurityWebFilterChain definitions. But it is not working. It is giving 401 for all urls.

```
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityWebFilterChain openAccess(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeExchange(
                exchanges ->
                        exchanges
                                .pathMatchers("/", "/ping", "/view/home", "/actuator/**")
                                .permitAll())
                .httpBasic()
                .disable()
                .formLogin()
                .disable()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityWebFilterChain apiSecurity(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeExchange(
                exchanges ->
                        exchanges
                                .pathMatchers("/api/user/")
                                .hasAuthority(
                                        PRODUCT
                                                .getAccessName()
                                                .toLowerCase()))
                .httpBasic()
                .disable()
                .formLogin()
                .disable()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(3)
    public SecurityWebFilterChain oauthAccess(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeExchange(
                exchanges ->
                        exchanges
                                .pathMatchers("/kp/oauth2/**")
                                .permitAll()
                                .pathMatchers("/login")
                                .authenticated())
                .httpBasic()
                .disable()
                .formLogin()
                .disable()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(
                        logoutSuccessHandler("/logout.com/logout?service=" + casServerUrl))
                .and()
                .oauth2Login();
        return http.build();
    }
```

Here are the application startup logs:
https://gist.github.com/rajeevprasanna/122b4e42f048b2c07eb80f60cd423f34

When I enter URL **http://localhost:8080/login** in the browser, it is giving a 401 error. want it to trigger OAuth flow as per my configuration
https://gist.github.com/rajeevprasanna/aa0d586fc86cbd31e103c5c3f8a3fc06

> **UPDATE**: i have tried modifying the code and added securityMatcher. but got into different issue with oauth authentication. issue posted
> separately on so:
> [Spring security not redirecting to given OAuth authentication URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67700589/spring-security-not-redirecting-to-given-oauth-authentication-url)

Comment: please update your question with your full debug logs, startup and request.

Comment: i see huge logs dump. which part of logs will help to understand the issue?

Comment: the startup logs, so we can see what is loaded. And then the logs when you do a request so we know what happens during a request.

Comment: @Toerktumlare added logs in description. pls check

Comment: can you please give some rough template. i am not getting what you mean by creating 3 different configuration classes not beans. please elaborate

Comment: if you dont understand, please use google, and read the documentation before asking. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#jc-webflux-multiple-filter-chains you need to use for instance a `PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher`

Comment: Thanks for the link. i didn't get good results. i might be searching with wrong keywords. sorry to bother you. But thank again for pointers