# Spring security not redirecting to given OAuth authentication URL

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to integrate oauth2 using spring security and added few security rules for protecting paths. When I try to access the secure URL, it is redirecting to the default authentication URL instead of taking the one from the application.yml file. can someone help me to understand what I am missing?

OAuth configuration in yml file

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          testProvider:
            client-id: test
            client-secret: xxx
            clientName: cas
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            redirect-uri: https://x.y.com/login/oauth2/code/idc
        provider:
          testProvider:
            authorization-uri: https://x.y.com/oauth2.0/authorize
            user-info-uri: https://x.y.com/oauth2.0/profile
            token-uri: https://x.y.com/oauth2.0/accessToken
            user-name-attribute: id
```

security dependencies:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
```

Rules in configured in security filter:

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityWebFilterChain openAccess(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.securityMatcher(new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher("/open"))
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges.anyExchange().permitAll())
                .httpBasic()
                .disable()
                .formLogin()
                .disable();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(3)
    public SecurityWebFilterChain oauthAccess(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
                .securityMatcher(new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher("/secure"))
                .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges.anyExchange().authenticated())
                .oauth2Login();
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

when i enter url **http://localhost:8080/secure** in browser, it is redirecting to **http://localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/testProvider** . It is not taking configured authorisation URL in yml file  **https://x.y.com/oauth2.0/authorize**

Code is uploaded into github: https://github.com/rajeevprasanna/webflux-oauth-test

Comment: When you add `EnableWebfluxSecurity` you are overriding the default security and you have to configure everything manually. Thats probably why it is not reading the yml. The documentation shows how to confige the oauth client manually.

Comment: When i remove securityMatcher, rules are not working properly. it is going to proper authorisation flow. With securityMatcher, authorisation flow failing. not sure why behavior is conflicting

Comment: this seems to be issue with securityMatcher. If i remove securityMatcher, route specific rules are not working

Answer (score 1):

The way that Spring Security starts the Authorization Code flow is by first doing a redirect to its own `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter` endpoint.

This endpoint will then look up values in the `ClientRegistration` and redirect to your configured value.

However, I believe there is an issue with your `securityMatcher` in that it says that Spring Security should only participate in requests that start with `/secure`. Once Spring Security redirects to `/oauth2/authorization/testProvider`, the filter chain is not used for that request (since it doesn't start with `/secure`).

To address this, I believe you should change this:

```java
.securityMatcher(new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher("/secure"))
```

to this:

```java
.securityMatcher(new OrServerWebExchangeMatcher(
    new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher("/secure"),
    new PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher("/oauth2")
))
```

Alternatively, Spring Security is designed to negotiate authorization rules for you in one DSL configuration. While there are reasonable use cases for having two different filter chains, you might instead consider having just one:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain web(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http
        .authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges
            .pathMatchers("/open").permitAll()
            .pathMatchers("/secure").authenticated()
        )
        .oauth2Login(Customizer.withDefaults());

    return http.build();
}
```

Then, the extra security matcher is unnecessary since this DSL is configured to filter all endpoints.

Additionally, `httpBasic` and `formLogin` are not initialized by default, so proactively disabling them is needless.

Comment: i was not able to import OrSecurityWebExchangeMatcher. is it part of boot:spring-boot-starter-security library?

Comment: Sorry for the typo there, it's been corrected.